# AppFabric session state provider - LRU eviction has been disabled for the cache used to store Session

Tags: appfabric

I'm using AppFabric to share session between 2 or more different Web Applications.

But I got a problem which said: "**Expected the Session item 'FULL_NAME' to be present in the cache, but it could not be found, indicating that the current Session is corrupted. Please verify that LRU eviction has been disabled for the cache used to store Session.**"

My configuration:

```
<dataCacheClient>
<hosts>
  <host name="CACHE1" cachePort="22233" />
  <host name="CACHE2" cachePort="22233" />
  <host name="CACHE3" cachePort="22233" />
</hosts>
```

```
<machineKey validationKey="C7415df6847D0C0B5146F5605B5973EBD59kjh67EE6414ECD534A95F528F153B6B5F42CFFA9EBF65B2169F7DA5D801C0F9053454A159505253DC687A" decryptionKey="3AE9EE73F1A2781B73DEC6C3fgdgdfD28E0C730284DD314118DA8B" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

<sessionState timeout="40" mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="XXXXX" shareID="YYYYY" retryCount="10" useBlobMode="false" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

is there anyone know what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the asp.net config you need to check, it's the cache itself.

On a cache host, see the output of the command `Get-CacheConfig XXXXX` - as the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921029(v=azure.10).aspx) say you will see output like this: check the `EvictionType`:

```
CacheName            : Cache1
TimeToLive           : 10 mins
CacheType            : Partitioned
Secondaries          : 0
IsExpirable          : True
EvictionType         : LRU
NotificationsEnabled : False
```

For more information on eviction settings, see the [Expiration and Eviction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790981(WS.10).aspx) documentation. If your eviction type is not LRU, check cache memory usage, as that page states:

> When the memory consumption of the cache service on a cache server
>   exceeds the low watermark threshold, AppFabric starts evicting objects
>   that have already expired. **When memory consumption exceeds the high
>   watermark threshold, objects are evicted from memory, regardless of
>   whether they have expired or not, until memory consumption goes back
>   down to the low watermark.**

There's an [expiration troubleshooting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921014(v=azure.10).aspx) page with more info.